# Angular $resource custom action undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### The problem

I'm trying to use the custom action of a service inside my controller but the function is not defined.

I have this factory:

```
var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:9232/api/';
var managerControllers = angular.module('managerControllers', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

managerControllers.factory('businessService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource(apiUrl+'Business/:bussinessId',
        {businessId: '@id'},
        {
            getSimple: {method:'GET', url: apiUrl+'Business/simple', isArray: true}
        });
}]);
```

And my controller:

```
managerControllers.controller('ProfessionalController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$resource', 'professionalService', 'businessService',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $resource, professionalService, businessService) {
        $scope.params = $routeParams;
        if($routeParams.id)
            $scope.professionals = professionalService.query({businessId: $routeParams.id});
        $scope.newProfessional = new professionalService();
        $scope.businessOptions = businessService.getSimple();
        this.addProfessional = function(professional){
            professional.$save();
            $scope.newProfessional = new professionalService();
        };
    }])
```

The businessServce.getSimple() is undefined.

**In the original controller's code I'm not passing $resource as a dependency. The objective is to use just the service. The $resource is just to be able to debug. I'll remove it once getSimple shows up on businessService**

### I've tried to...

...put a  breakpoint on the call, and the getSimple() function doesn't show up. It really is undefined, although I don't know why.

Then on chrome's console I created a new $resource using the same code inside the factory and the getSimple showed up fine.

### Question

Is there anything else I need to do to expose the getSimple I declared on the businessService using the $resource?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your resource definition is OK - if I use it separately, businessService.getSimple is a function (see http://jsbin.com/cafupu/1/edit?js,console,output)

In your example is used inline anotated code

```
['serviceA', function(serviceA){}]
```

Is possible you removed only anotation, but no function parameter?

Synchronization anotation definition and function parameters is common problem, therefore I prefer simple functions for writing (used in jsbin) and https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate for automatical anotation before minification.

Comment: If I understood, you are sugesting me to instead of doing ['serviceA', function(serviceA){}], do just function(serviceA){} ? Isn't the annotation needed so the injector knows what is needed to be injected into the controller? Anyway, I'll try that once I get home. Thanks!

Comment: angular injector support three formats for anotation see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector
For minification you need "stringly" anotated code, but there is no reason to write it manually.

Because everything written in two places is potentially error.

Comment: I removed the annotation but the problem persists... getSimple is still undefined inside the controller.

Comment: What is the content of variable businessService? It's really Resource instance? (http://jsbin.com/cafupu/4/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: It is... it has a save, get and query among other things. But no getSimple :(